# Possible to bring Rule Line Mark in Webcomposer (Monaco Editor)?

Tags: monaco-editor, linemark

We planned to bring rule line mark functionality in Web Composer(Using Monaco Editor) as like in Standalone composer.

Can we implement the same functionality in Web Composer(Monaco Editor). Rule Line Mark Functionality in Standalone composer:

[image: Rule Line Mark Functionality in Standalone composer]

Can anyone let me know, is that possible to bring this functionality in Web composer?.

Comment: What you want is implemented via decorarions. See the https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#interfaces/editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor.html#createDecorationsCollection